# Can I map all of physical memory in driver and give access to userspace. Is it possible possibly with remap_pfn_range

Tags: c, linux-kernel

So I like to create dmidecode type of utility. So Just let the user mmap and give access. Its done in that. I know I can use `remap_pfn_range` this is the signature

```
int remap_pfn_range(struct vm_area_struct *, unsigned long addr,
            unsigned long pfn, unsigned long size, pgprot_t);
```

what should I pass for  pgprot_t and size I. And what is`unsigned long pnf` and does addr is base address where the mapping should start.

Also what my userspace mmap call will look like

Comment: /dev/mem already does this.

Comment: @stark it's a char device /dev/mem. And it limits 1 mb map from userspace and also that only sized read. I need to read more than that

Comment: `int remap_pfn_range (structure vm_area_struct *vma, unsigned long addr,
                     unsigned long pfn, unsigned` this function takes pfn so what would be the pfn for start of physical memory. Can any can now please let me know. Should I just write 0x00 for pfn in remap_pfn_range. I idea is I want to read all of bios info at least. I believe bios info is at the start of physical memory. Dmidecode also reads it but the limit of read and mapping of char /dev/mem makes it impossible for dmidecode to read all pcie devices that I am looking into.

Comment: See the "simple" implementation in chapter 15 of Linux Device Drivers, Third Edition (LDD3). A more up-to-date version is [here](https://github.com/martinezjavier/ldd3/tree/master/simple).